# How to force X to re-theme all open windows to current X resources?

Tags: linux, xorg

I've got a ~/.Xdefaults that has a specific color theme defined for Xorg, and this works.  I've got a ~/.XdefaultsNew that specifies an alternate color theme.  Xorg starts and loads ~/.Xdefaults which is correct.  After running some applications, I run

> xrdb ~/.XdefaultsNew

This overrides all my X resources to the new defined values (correctly).  If I open a new window, the theme is seen correctly.  However, all the previously opened windows retain the original theme.

Is there a way to force X to "re-theme" all windows it is managing with the currently loaded X resources?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for applications that implement the Editres protocol, and that support SetValues requests (see `editres(1)` for a user-level description and `/usr/include/X11/Xmu/EditresP.h` for a programmer-level description).

You can watch the Editres protocol in action by launching the `editres` program. In the menu, select “Commands / Get Tree” and click on the editres window, then select “Tree / Select Widget in Client” and click somewhere in the editres window again. Select “Commands / Show Resource Box”, click on “background” in the normal resources list, and enter a color name where it says “Enter Resource Value”, then click on “Apply” and watch part of the editres window change color.

Unfortunately, while most applications that use X resources understand the Editres protocol, few implement the SetValues part. It's a good idea that hardly anyone bothered to implement.